# PostGIS: Transform Linestring to LineString ZM

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

**Problem:**

I have a series of geometries (`LineString`) saved in a Postgres database with additional information saved next to the geometry (a column for speed and time). I want to combine the three columns into a `LineString ZM` type so the geometry goes from a 2d to a 4d vector.

| id | geometry | speed | time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | LineString_A | Int[] | Float[] |
| 2 | LineString_B | Int[] | Float[] |

**Question:**

How do I most easily combine the `geometry` (x, y), `speed`, and `time` into a `LineString ZM`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for [`ST_Force4D`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Force_4D.html).

All you need to do is to `ALTER TABLE` using the values you already have in the columns `speed` and `time`, e.g.

```
ALTER TABLE your_table ALTER COLUMN geom TYPE geometry (linestringzm, 4326) 
USING ST_Force4D(geom,speed,time);
```

### **Demo (PostGIS 3.1)**

```
CREATE TABLE t (geom geometry(linestring,4326), speed int, time numeric);
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('SRID=4326;LINESTRING(30 10,10 30,40 40)'::geometry,42,1230);

ALTER TABLE t ALTER COLUMN geom type geometry (linestringzm, 4326) 
USING ST_Force4D(geom,speed,time);

SELECT ST_AsText(geom) FROM t;

                         st_astext                         
-----------------------------------------------------------
 LINESTRING ZM (30 10 42 1230,10 30 42 1230,40 40 42 1230)
```

**Different scenario** (see comments): `speed` and `time` are arrays that overlap 1:1 with the points in the LineString.

```
CREATE TABLE t
(id int, geom geometry(linestring,4326), speed int[], time numeric[]);
INSERT INTO t VALUES
(1,'SRID=4326;LINESTRING(30 10, 10 30, 40 40)'::geometry,ARRAY[1,2,3],ARRAY[1230,1231,1232]),
(2,'SRID=4326;LINESTRING(50 60, 70 80, 90 95)'::geometry,ARRAY[4,5,6],ARRAY[1458,1459,1500]);
```

Since you cannot [`unnest`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html) an array in a `ALTER TABLE` statement, you could just change the data type from LineString to LineStringZM and set the extra dimensions temporarily to `0`:

```
ALTER TABLE t ALTER COLUMN geom TYPE geometry (linestringzm, 4326) 
USING ST_Force4D(geom,0,0);
```

The following [`CTE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) dumps all points from your LineStrings, create new ones with `Z` and `M` dimensions, and finally creates the LineStringZM for the `UPDATE` query.

```
WITH j AS (
  SELECT id, ST_MakeLine(j.pointzm) AS linestringzm
  FROM (SELECT id, geom AS linestring,
          (ST_DumpPoints(geom)).path AS path,
           ST_MakePoint(ST_X((ST_DumpPoints(geom)).geom),
                       ST_Y((ST_DumpPoints(geom)).geom),
                       unnest(speed),unnest(time)) AS pointzm
  FROM t ORDER BY id,path) j
  GROUP BY id 
)
UPDATE t SET geom = j.linestringzm
FROM j WHERE t.id = j.id;

SELECT id, ST_AsText(geom) FROM t;

 id |                       st_astext                        
----+--------------------------------------------------------
  1 | LINESTRING ZM (30 10 1 1230,10 30 2 1231,40 40 3 1232)
  2 | LINESTRING ZM (50 60 4 1458,70 80 5 1459,90 95 6 1500)
(2 rows)
```

Further reading:

- [`ST_DumpPoints`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DumpPoints.html)
- [`ST_MakeLine`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakeLine.html)

Comment: Arr, nice! Didn't know the `ST_Force4D` function. There is a little twist. The `speed` and `time` column is an array _(See example above)_ that maps 1-to-1 to each point in the LineString. Can `ST_Force4D` still be used to 'zip' the geometry and the `time` and `speed` column?

Comment: @SOK do the geometries have a pk or a unique id? I'm afraid the query will get a little longer, but I believe it is possible

Comment: Not as is; I have an id column next to the geometry which maybe could be used?

Comment: @SOK an id would make things much more safe. In case the lines do not repeat, you can use it as in the example above (see my edit)

Comment: Thanks! :) the `id` column is the PK - Can't that be used to safely update it or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: @SOK yes, the id can be used and is a much more reliable choice than `geom`. See my last edit

Comment: @JimJones, incredibly complete answer! Well done! Just what I needed.

Comment: @JohnZastrow always nice to hear. Thanks!